# The definition and meaning of "machine epsilon" in MATLAB

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I am taking a introductory course in numerical mathematics, using MATLAB and a numerical math text that refers to MATLAB often. In the text, the machine precision is defined as:

> The distance $\epsilon$ between 1 and the next largest floating point number that can be represented in the system.

In MATLAB, the command help('eps') agrees, stating:

> eps, with no arguments, is the distance from 1.0 to the next larger double
>       precision number.

Now, my understanding is that this should mean that $1+\epsilon$ is the smallest number greater than 1 that can be represented, so we should have: $$1+0.9\epsilon = 1$$ $$1+\epsilon \ne 1$$

However, in MATLAB, the number that I intuitively understand to have the properties of $\epsilon$ seems to actually be just above $\epsilon/2$. Observe that the code

```
    1+eps==1
    1+eps*0.9==1
    1+eps*0.51==1
    1+eps*0.5==1
```

Produces the output:

```
    ans = 0
    ans = 0
    ans = 0
    ans = 1
```

How am I misinterpreting the definition of eps? Is is because some of these numbers are not normalized?

Comment: My guess is that $1 + \epsilon*0.9$ gets rounded up to $1 + \epsilon$; in fact $1 + \epsilon * 0.9 == 1 + \epsilon$ should output $1$ (and $\epsilon * 0.9 == \epsilon$ should output $0$!)

Comment: But $\epsilon*0.9$ evaluates as 1.9984e-16, which makes sense because $\epsilon$ exceeds eps(0). What I don't understand is that from what I have been taught, the sum of a number less than eps(1) = $\epsilon$ and 1 should be 1.

Comment: No, $1 + \epsilon * 0.9$ is closer to $1 + \epsilon$ than it is to $1$, therefore it makes sense to round it up to $1 + \epsilon$

Comment: Sorry, I misread "ϵ∗0.9==ϵ should output 0" as "ϵ∗0.9 should output 0." Thanks. Basically it boils down to the fact that MATLAB rounds instead of just truncating. Duh! You could make that answer if you'd like.

Comment: @dani_s But this rounding supposes that the parser is catching this before it executes the command and that seems unlikely. By definition, the output of the FPU wen adding $1$ and any number smaller than $\epsilon$ should again be $1$.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Why would it behave like that? I honestly have no idea how an FPU works internally but there should be an option to choose a rounding mode

Comment: @dani_s So instead of just adding the two inputs, there would have to be logic that analyzed each and modified either the inputs or the addition logic? I am no expert here, so this could be way off, but that just seems unlikely to me. Without this extra logic, there is nothing to round since $1+x \epsilon = 1 \;\; \forall \;\; \vert x \vert < 1$. This question might be better suited to the computational science board or somewhere else where experts on the IEEE floating-point standard visit.

Comment: @dani_s Perhaps an FPU uses more bits in the addition than they return? That would make the rounding much simpler and not require any extra logic up front. A quick search turned up this page of [extended precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision), which is probably what is going on under the hood.